# ¿Qué hacer con preguntas que son sólo código?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

Últimamente he visto un patrón de preguntas por diferentes usuarios (y no únicamente usuarios nuevos) que lo único que hacen es poner código (sólo código) en el cuerpo de la pregunta sin descripción alguna del problema ni mensaje de error que acompañe al código; y otra variante parecida que es cuando sólo ponen el mensaje de error (un largo stack trace) también sin ningún tipo de descripción y además sin código. Para colmo, no formatean el código/mensaje de error, con lo cual se ve muy mal y es difícil de leer.

Normalmente voto por cerrarlas porque las considero de baja calidad y, aunque tratan de programación, considero que no se ajustan a los temas pertinentes del sitio según el centro de ayuda... Pero parece que esas preguntas son aceptadas por la comunidad (o por cierta parte de ella) como adecuadas y reciben votos positivos y respuestas (algunas veces no muy acertadas por la evidente falta de información).

¿Qué se debería hacer con esas preguntas?

Answer (score -3):

Quizá se deba añadir un aviso en los comentarios, para que la modifique o será borrada en X intervalo de tiempo por considerarla de baja calidad.