# Añadamos una alerta en preguntas que son solo código

Tags: característica-nueva, advertencias-en-preguntas

### Actualización

#### Resumen

> **Den su opinion y voten en esta pregunta: [¿Están de acuerdo con poner una validación a preguntas que son código unicamente?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3743/22721)**

#### Explicación

Al parecer esto no será tan simple como se pensaba, **pero se puede hacer**.
Nicolas nuestro nuevo CM dijo [esto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47394733#47394733) en el chat de [La terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) (que es lo mismo que lo que nos dijo g3rv4 en la respuesta, ¡gracias!).

> I asked my coworkers. They say that the feature is not activated on any int'l sites. Basically that means we probably do not know if it works well with non English texts. If we activate the feature, we need to be carefully about new users and wait for their feedback. That might affect QPD. Please let me know if the community is ready and agrees with that.

A continuación pondré una traducción mía, siéntase libres de editarla si encuentran alguna inconsistencia

> Pregunté a mis compañeros de trabajo. Dicen que esa característica no está activada en ningún sitio internacional. Básicamente eso significa que probablemente no sabemos si funciona bien con textos que no están en inglés. Si activamos esa característica, tenemos que ser cuidadosos con los nuevos usuarios y esperar por su retroalimentación. Esto puede afectar las PPD (Preguntas por día). Por favor hazme saber si la comunidad está lista y de acuerdo con aquello.

Según entendí el primer paso es que estemos de acuerdo en implementarlas, después de saber que puede ser afectado.

---

Hoy me encontré con un problema y pensé que tal vez la comunidad de SOen me podría ayudar, así que me decidí por hacer una pregunta.

Puse el título y empecé a redactarla. Como no se me ocurría nada pensé en poner el código formateado primero y luego ir describiendo el problema, copié el código de mi editor de texto lo pegué y aplasté su respectivo <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>.

En lo que iba a mi editor de texto por el resto de código me encontré con esto:

[image: alerta de pregunta]

Se puede ver claramente la alerta que nos dice

> Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

A la final en lo que hacía la pregunta se me ocurrió la solución, pero me dio curiosidad ver si teniamos lo mismo en nuestro SOes, así que hice los mismos pasos y...

[image: sin alerta]

... nada.

Luego procedí a hacer la busqueda en [traducir.win](https://traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=add%20some%20context) (porque estoy seguro que no quiero fallar) y encontré que sí existe la traducción.

**En conclusión**

Pienso que esta "nueva" característica es necesaria ya que no solo beneficiaría a mejorar la calidad de preguntas nuevas, sino que también ayudaría a disminuir la carga a nuestros moderadores y a los que frecuentamos las colas de revisión. Y quién sabe, en una de esas hasta ayuda a que los usuarios nuevos lean los enlaces en el Centro de Ayuda.

---

Relacionado:

- [Advertencias en preguntas potencialemente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3299/advertencias-en-preguntas-potencialemente-problem%c3%a1ticas) (?)
- [¿Qué hacer con preguntas que son sólo código?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/913/qu%c3%a9-hacer-con-preguntas-que-son-s%c3%b3lo-c%c3%b3digo)

Comment: ¡Gran pregunta! Viendo el texto de ayuda que aparece en amarillo a la derecha uno no puede dejar de pensar: ¿cómo podemos seguir con una guía tan parca en palabras y que deja tantas cosas en el tintero? A ver si se activa ya la nueva página para preguntar, más interactiva.

Comment: Buena propuesta, esperemos que pronto esa alerta este disponible aquí también.

Comment: Deberiamos aprovechar y copiar la expresion regular que tienen los muchachos alla... otra mas para gerv.. pobre nos va a matar cuando vuelva...

Comment: Es una buena idea. Todo lo que sea añadir filtros al crear una pregunta será una manera de evitar que muchas preguntas inadecuadas en SOes y también que se llenan de comentarios sobre como hacer preguntas y los votos en contra (negativos) en preguntas que en algunos casos pueden ser muy interesantes en la comunidad si se realizan correctamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta funcionalidad no está activada en SOes. Para activarla, tendríamos que habilitar una funcionalidad en `/ask` para que usuarios con menos rep que un límite definido hagan una "prueba de formato" (que no tengo idea de qué es).

Por lo que veo, no está habilitado en ninguno de los sitios internacionales.

Esta no va por expresiones regulares. Yo diría que o crees una nueva pregunta con [característica-nueva](/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva) o edites esta pregunta.

Vamos a necesitar de la ayuda de JuanM.

Comment: ¿Crees que valga la pena llevarlo a [meta.se]?

Comment: si, totalmente :)