# Mensaje: Your post is mostly code

Tags: discusión

Es la primera vez que hago consultas en este foro, mejor dicho que lo intenté y me saltó el mensaje:

> Your post is mostly code

Que mi consulta era principalmente código, y así era (concretamente HTML5 y JQuery). ¿Qué patrón debo seguir para hacer una consulta donde prácticamente solo hay código?

Comment: Si es posible ¿podrías poner una captura de pantalla?

Comment: Puede ser que esté relacionado con [Alerta en preguntas que son solo código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3491/alerta-en-preguntas-que-son-solo-c%c3%b3digo)

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenido Victor B.

Si no lo has hecho aún favor de revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

En cuanto a las preguntas sobre HTML y jQuery te podría servir usar un [Stack Snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65) y por favor no pegues tu proyecto completo, sólo agrega un ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable.

En cuanto al mensaje, eso es algo que recientemente que se había solicitado. Es probable que hayas sido el primero en compartir que lo ha visto en Stack Overflow en español.

Relacionado

- [Alerta en preguntas que son solo código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3491/65)