# ¿Están de acuerdo con poner una validación a preguntas que son código unicamente?

Tags: característica-nueva, advertencias-en-preguntas

Esta pregunta deriva de [Añadamos una alerta en preguntas que son solo código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3491).

[g3rv4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) como siempre atento [publicó una respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3518) en la que nos decía

> Para activarla, tendríamos que habilitar una funcionalidad en /ask para que usuarios con menos rep que un límite definido hagan una "prueba de formato" (que no tengo idea de qué es).

Luego de un tiempo [cambiamos de CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313084) y Nicolas [dijo esto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47394733#47394733)

> I asked my coworkers. They say that the feature is not activated on any int'l sites. Basically that means we probably do not know if it works well with non English texts. If we activate the feature, we need to be carefully about new users and wait for their feedback. That might affect QPD. Please let me know if the community is ready and agrees with that.

A continuación pondré una traducción mía, siéntase libres de editarla si encuentran alguna inconsistencia

> Pregunté a mis compañeros de trabajo. Dicen que esa característica no está activada en ningún sitio internacional. Básicamente eso significa que probablemente no sabemos si funciona bien con textos que no están en inglés. Si activamos esa característica, tenemos que ser cuidadosos con los nuevos usuarios y esperar por su retroalimentación. Esto puede afectar las PPD (Preguntas por día). Por favor hazme saber si la comunidad está lista y de acuerdo con aquello.

---

#### En resumen

Para poner en marcha esta iniciativa primero necesitamos saber sus opiniones al respecto conociendo el panorama completo, así que, **voten en esta pregunta si están de acuerdo o no, si tienen una opinión al respecto no duden en compartirla.**

Comment: bueno esa seria buena idea pero creo que  seria algo complicado aplicarlo,lo que yo recomendaria es quizar orientar de una buena manera a los nuevos o sencillamente borrar sus preguntar quiza seria algo drastico pero es solo un opcion quiza alguien tiene una mejor idea que nos ayude a todos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Muchas gracias a [@Konamiman](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman?tab=profile) por la traducción.

---

Hemos activado dos verificaciones a este respecto:

- La verificación #1 impone una cierta relación entre líneas de código y caracteres de texto en una pregunta. Con demasiado código / demasiado poco texto la pregunta será rechazada con un mensaje solicitando una explicación más extendida del código.
- La verificación #2 establece un umbral por debajo del cual las aportaciones de los usuarios serán comprobadas usando a un conjunto de heurísticas para intentar identificar código que no está adecuadamente formateado como tal.

Ambas comprobaciones son configurables. Por el momento la #1 está establecida como "6 caracteres de texto por 1 línea de código", y la #2 está establecida a "200 puntos de reputación". Durante las próximas semanas tenemos que vigilar los números y ajustar las verificaciones, o desactivarlas si algo va mal.

Por favor, decidme qué os parece.

Comment: ¡Gran noticia! Muchas gracias Nicolas por implementarlo.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Nicolas for everything you are doing for the internartional SO community. I’ll translate the answer as soon as I arrive to the office, if it isn’t translated by then

Comment: Interesante, pero que sucedería si los comentarios del código son la explicación?

Comment: Creo que no sería un caso válido para quitar la validación @ManuelRobles. El autor siempre puede poner esos comentarios en el cuerpo de la pregunta explicando el problema y no dentro del bloque de código donde es casi seguro que se pierdan

Answer (score 5):

Totalmente de acuerdo; considero que serviría como apoyo para:

> 1. orientar antes de publicar(así como cuando por coincidencias con el título te muestra posibles preguntas similares a la tuya)
> 2. Sería un primer filtro para que los nuevos usuarios, se den el tiempo de revisar mas a detalle el ¿cómo se debería estar publicando?

Alguna ocasiones los usuarios sobre todo los nuevos, no se toman el tiempo de revisar:

> 1. el tour
> 2. como preguntar
> 3. publicaciones de otros usuarios para tener una referencia de que se espera de sus preguntas

Como sería una característica propia del sistema, ayudaría a que el OP comprenda que no es una opinión o exigencia de algún usuario de la comunidad; sino que es una regla que se debe de cumplir y que aplica para todos los que usamos **SO EN ESPAÑOL**

> Sin embargo, también se debería tener presente para la sección de
>   respuestas; SO en español se distingue por la calidad del contenido
>   que como comunidad aportamos sin embargo responder solo con un script
>   que aunque pudiera ser correcto no explica su existencia en si mismo
>   se torna como contenido difícil de usar con el paso del tiempo

Comment: bueno yo si lo vi el tour y todo eso :p