# Recorrido obligatorio y eliminación de imágenes para usuarios nuevos

Tags: característica-nueva, usuarios-nuevos, recorrido

¿Existe alguna forma de agregar una recomendación a Stack Overflow para que incluya un recorrido por la página al crear tu cuenta?

Ya que todos los usuarios nuevos caen en lo mismo de publicar imágenes para que se les ayude en vez de publicar el código como tal, ¿por qué no incluimos dos limitaciones pare ellos?

- Que para el usuario sea obligado a ir a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), o
- Que se le limite el uso de imágenes hasta llegar a cierta puntuación.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, no existe algo así. Quizás deberías plantearlo en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). No porque no sea interesante (que lo es), pero el alcance de esta petición parece mucho mayor que sólo nuestro sitio.

Comment: muchas gracias lo hare.

Comment: Cuando se crea una cuanta hay un pequeño recorrido, pero para el resto estan los moderadores y nosotros los usuarios para informar. Puede ser tedioso, quizas, pero no esta mal... nos ayuda a nosotros a recordar lo que debemos hacer.

Comment: Busca antes, porque me imagino que alguna sugerencia como esta se habrá hecho ya (aunque puede que haya sido borrada si recibió muchos negativos). Y ten en cuenta que metaSE a veces es algo _hostil_.

Comment: ¿Qué pasaría si un usuario desea incluir una imagen de como se tiene que ver una interfaz gráfica vs como la tiene al momento?

Comment: El primer punto siempre es discutible ya que lo que puede suceder es que el usuario lo salte facilmente sin revisar la información ya que no conoce el ecosistema de SO y solo quiere una respuesta *urgente* a su pregunta

Answer (score 2):

En Stack Overflow (en inglés), cuando un usuario tiene reputación inferior a 10 (es decir, cuando aún le aplican las [restricciones de usuario nuevo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)) e intenta subir una imagen le aparece este mensaje:

> [image]

([fuente](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/1983854))

Este cambio de imagen por enlace ocurre en los sitios en los que los usuarios nuevos no pueden subir imágenes. Lo que no sé es si Stack Overflow en español pertenece a ese grupo. Yo por ejemplo he intentado subir una al formular una pregunta sin ninguna sesión abierta y me ha dejado:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No le he dado a enviar, por lo que no sé si realmente me dejaría publicarlo o no. Habría que hacer la prueba o bien consultarlo con [Nicolas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10/nicolas-chabanovsky).

Por tanto sí, sugiero activar la limitación de subir imágenes a usuarios nuevos en Stack Overflow en español.

Comment: mmm.. eso que pasa en SO parece peor.. no le dejo subir la imagen, pero le genero un link? o sea en lugar de la imagen hay un link a la imagen o lo entiendo mal?

Comment: @gbianchi entiendes bien.

Comment: ... ummm ... lo veo una bunena opción. Si genera el link, y la imagen **es necesaria o aclaratoria** en la pregunta, otro usuario con mayor rep. puede editar y hacerla visible ¿ no ?

Comment: @Trauma en SOen un usuario que tiene el privilegio de editar puede hacer visible la imagen.

Comment: @eyllanesc Pues eso digo, que me parece una buena opción **impedir** que el OP muestre la imagen, aunque **si** se genere el *link* a la misma.

Comment: @Trauma okay, entendí  mal tu comentario, y a mi tambien me parece bien :-)

Comment: Entonces se implemento o no? Yo creo que es buena opcion

Comment: @JuanRivera se implementó esto: [validación a preguntas que son código unicamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3743/83), lo de las imágenes no. Más info en [¿Qué hacer con “Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4172/83)