# ¿Con qué frecuencia los usuarios nuevos utilizan las imágenes en sustitución de explicaciones?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Al hilo de la pregunta [Recorrido obligatorio y eliminación de imágenes para usuarios nuevos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4003/83) surgió el siguiente debate: en Stack Overflow (en inglés) un [usuario nuevo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) (<10 rep) no tiene permiso para subir imágenes. Si lo hace, el sistema se la sube pero no la muestra, sino que pone el enlace a la imagen. Además, le pone el mensaje:

> [image]

Nicolas comenta que los encargados de configurar estas cosas para SOes le han dicho:

> The deciding factor here should be whether new users generally use images appropriately - that is, if new users often post inappropriate images, or use images in lieu of descriptions, or post unnecessary images, then we should block embedding.
>
> <sub>[The Terminal, 25 marzo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49633289#49633289)</sub>

Es decir:

> Aquí, el factor decisivo debería ser si los usuarios nuevos tienden a usar las imágenes correctamente o si, por contra, las utilizan en lugar de describir sus problemas, o bien añadiendo imágenes innecesarias. Si eso último ocurre, la incrustación de imágenes debería ser bloqueada para esos nuevos usuarios.

Por tanto, creo que sería interesante que la gente contestara aquí de la forma más objetiva y contrastable posible:

- ¿Con qué frecuencia observáis a usuarios con reputación de <10 utilizando correctamente la subida de imágenes?
- ¿En qué porcentaje de casos se usan las imágenes en lugar de explicaciones?

En función de los resultados se podría solicitar el bloqueo en la incrustación de imágenes.

Comment: Yo diría que muy pocas son realmente utiles. Son capturas de sus IDE's; codigo y errores. Las únicas válidas serian los pantallazos a interfaces pero tampoco suelen aclarar mucho el problema.

Comment: @lois6b interesante. ¿Podrías decir en qué porcentaje, aprox?

Comment: Puf, haciendo recapitulación mental... sobre el 20% de las veces las imágenes en usuarios nuevos son útiles..siendo optimistas.  Al menos es mi impresión.

Comment: Voy a ver si puedo hacer algunas consultas en sede.. esto deberia poder medirse de alguna manera...

Comment: @gbianchi se me ocurre consultar aquellas preguntas de usuarios nuevos que contengan "imgur" y el tamaño de la publicación sea reducido (número de palabras o caracteres). Luego se podría afinar un poco.

Comment: pensaba buscar usr con menos de 100 de rep durante el ultimos mes, y que dijera eso.. pensamos similar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como complemento a la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4021/10) de  [gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi), comparto estadísticas con la comunidad.

```
TotalImagePosts PctDeletedOrImageEditedOut TotalNewUserImagePosts PctNewUserDeletedOrImageEditedOut
--------------- -------------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------------------   
10996           22.862859221535            4857                   30.780317068149
```

Muchas gracias a [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) por la query. Yo la entiendo como:

- `TotalImagePosts` es cuántas publicaciones con una imagen en su contenido se han publicado en el sitio por parte de todos los usuarios.
- `PctDeletedOrImageEditedOut` es el porcentaje de publicaciones borradas o publicaciones de donde una imagen se ha eliminado.
- `TotalNewUserImagePosts` es cuántas publicaciones con una imagen en su contenido se han publicado, solamente por parte de nuevos usuarios.
- `PctNewUserDeletedOrImageEditedOut` es el porcentaje de publicaciones borradas o publicaciones de donde una imagen se ha eliminado, de entre las publicadas por usuarios nuevos.

Estos datos son de los últimos 365 días. Ojalá estas estadísticas ayuden a la comunidad a tomar una mejor decisión.

*Actualización*

Estadísticamente las publicaciones de los usuarios nuevos son editadas o eliminadas mas a menudo que las de la "población en general": en un 0.308% con un intervalo de confianza de [0.295, 0.321] cuando el mismo porcentaje para la población general es de 0.229.

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Muchas gracias por la traducción!

Comment: Thanks a lot to you Nicolas for investigating into this with "secret" data!! It is great to have it. If my maths are correct, the percentage of deleted or image edited out on non-new users would be around 16%, about half than on new users (2513 out of 10996 overall vs 1494 out of 4857 new users makes it 1018 out of 6139). To me it looks like there is some abuse of image specially by new users.

Comment: @fedorqui He actualizado el post. Sí, estás en lo correcto. Publicaciones de nuevos usuarios editadas o eliminadas más a menudo.

Answer (score 2):

A ver... Empecemos...

En la siguiente [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1015925/post-with-image-from-low-rep-users), obtenemos *las publicaciones (los posts)* de este año para usuarios con menos de 100 de reputación al día de la fecha.

```sql
select p.id [Post Link], p.body, owneruserid [User Link]
from posts p inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where
    p.body like '%imgur.com%' 
    and p.posttypeid = 1 
    and p.CreationDate > '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
    and u.reputation < 100
```

Esto nos da un resultado de 1400 publicaciones (estos números pueden cambiar al momento de ejecutar).

Ahora ejecutamos [las otras publicaciones](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1015937/post-without-image-from-low-rep-users), que no tienen imágenes:

```sql
select p.id [Post Link], p.body, owneruserid [User Link]
from posts p inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where
    p.body not like '%imgur.com%' 
    and p.posttypeid = 1 
    and p.CreationDate > '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
    and u.reputation < 100
```

Y ahora tenemos 5700 publicaciones.

Con un poco de matemáticas, nos damos cuenta que sobre un total de 7100 publicaciones, nos da que un %19 de las publicaciones tendría al menos una imagen.

Ahora, probemos refinar la búsqueda a aquellas publicaciones que tengan menos de 500 caracteres.

Ahora hagamos unos lindos gráficos.

[Publicaciones con imágenes por fecha:](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1015939/post-with-image-from-low-rep-users-by-date#graph)

[image: Publicaciones con imágenes por fecha.]

[Publicaciones, sin imágenes, por fecha:](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1015944/post-without-image-from-low-rep-users-by-date#graph)

[image: Publicaciones, sin imágenes, por fecha.]

Y ahora un [cuadro comparativo](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1015947/post-with-image-from-low-rep-users-compared-with-post-without-images#graph) entre ellos:

[image: Cuadro comparativo.]

Y un [porcentaje](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1015947/post-with-image-from-low-rep-users-compared-with-post-without-images#graph), hay días con muchas publicaciones con imágenes:

[image: Publicaciones con imágenes.]

Obviamente esto no implica nada... Habría que revisar cada publicación. Pero por lo menos, nos da un número para empezar a pensar.

Comment: se podria comparar estos datos con publicaciones con respuesta aceptada, o posts con imagenes y votos positivos?

Comment: Sería genial poder lanzar la consulta contra la base de datos entera a la que tienen acceso los CM y que contiene las publicaciones borradas, más que nada para que el [Sesgo del superviviente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) no fuera tan acentuado: ahora mismo solo vemos las preguntas que han "sobrevivido" al Roomba, cuando seguramente las que más datos nos darían son las que no lo han hecho.

Comment: @fedorqui las preguntas borradas tienen que estar ahi.. deberiamos investigar sede un poco mas... es bueno esa idea...

Comment: @lois6b todo se puede!!! este es un primer intento...

Comment: @gbianchi no: SEDE solo devuelve datos de publicaciones que son visibles. Las borradas solo pueden verlas los CM en su dump privado.

Comment: @fedorqui grrr.. entonces no sabria que where usar...