# ¿Qué hacer con quienes muestran código en imágenes en vez de en texto?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, imágenes

Desde que empece a colaborar en la comunidad he visto como muchisimos usuarios(nuevos) hacen sus preguntas y ponen su codigo como una imagen.

Este es el formulario de formulacion de preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ningun lugar se ve (al menos de manera obvia), algo que avise al usuario de manera clara y precisa de que los codigos no se ponen como imagen.

Porque no poner un texto en este formulario que sea super que obvio, avisando al usuario de que no se puede poner el codigo como imagen? Si el texto no es obvio, entonces el problema va a continuar.

Hacer esto creo que ahorraria trabajo de moderacion ya que a veces cansa y desgasta repetir tantas veces a usuarios nuevos lo que se debe hacer

Comment: A mi me parece bien. Debemos averiguar si ese texto se puede cambiar, porque esto viene de una [traduccion](https://es.traducir.win/strings/14792) y la misma no tiene un link a ningun lado. Tal vez, solo deba agregarse un cartel que diga, no uses imagenes para mostrar tu codigo. Igual, esto casi seguro que no va a evitar nada...

Comment: en otros sitios como github cuando van a reportar un issues el equipos suele colocar una plantilla... eso deberia ser un feature de cada sitio en la red y que cada sitio tenga su plantalla depndiendo de sus necesidades... pero colocarlo en otro lugar seria igual que el tour... la gente no le presta atencion y se los saltan...

Comment: En sitios grandes los usuarios nuevos on pueden publicar imágenes ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/209901)) y les sale una indicación ([fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267491/209901)). Si a ello le unimos la [limitación de que cada pregunta debe tener al menos un % de no código, es decir explicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3743/83), nos podría salir un filtro bastante útil.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', de acuerdo totalmente contigo

Comment: @gbianchi, tiene que ser un texto que llame la atención, si se va a poner uno en arial 10 y de color amarillo por supuesto que va a pasar desapercibido, tiene que ser algo que provoque que el usuario dirija su vista allí, quizá algún efecto visual, no se, la respuesta de fedorqui estuvo muy buena, creo que por ahí debe ir la cosa

Comment: El tema de las imagenes.. es que si la pregunta es sobre mi sitio web, y explico, pongo 10 lineas de codigo, y una foto de como se ve mal, la pregunta es correcta con imagen y todo... pero se va a quejar que tiene una imagen.. es algo mas complejo....

Comment: el problema es que contenga las imagenes, si el problema es de codigo y la imagen es el codigo esta mal la pregunta por que no somos transcriptores de codigo... si la pregunta es de diseño y se adjunta una imagen del diseño y nada mas, mal por que no somos adivinos y no sabemos que esta afectando al diseño... toda pregunta quesea de diseño o codigo debe tener codigo en formato de codigo (texto) ... toda pregunta que sea de diseño o de un box de configuracio(de una herramienta de programacion) debe tener un ejemplo reproducible o una imagen delproblema y el resultado esperdo

Comment: las preguntas que no cumplan con lo minimo para ser resueltas o que alguien las resuelva deben ser cerradas... independientemente tengan codigo imajenes o link... tambien concidero que deben ser cerradas inmediatamente... 2 votos... y darle tiempo al op para validar las normas del sitio, la mayoria que caen en esto es por que no las han leidos o prentenden pasarcelas por donde no les llega el sol...

Comment: en teoria las imagenes deben ser un recurso opcional, para que se enriquezcan la pregunta, no para satanizarlas... y dar una mejor idea del resultado esperado o el esquema aplicado...

Comment: @gbianchi como todo cambio en este sitio, debe basarse en datos: ¿en qué proporción de casos una imagen de un usuario nuevo es útil respecto el total? Si el número es alto, pues no; si por lo contrario muchas veces es la excusa perfecta para una pregunta mal formulada, puede ser útil caparlo.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' esto ya lo discutimos.. buscare esa publicacion...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿[esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4048/83)?

Comment: Ese cartel ya existe, cuando el OP hace la revisión de la pregunta, aparece abajo en una lista de sugerencias. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ctst.png

Comment: Tal vez esa sugerencia debería de ser más visible, ya que al parecer muchos publican la pregunta sin leerla...

Comment: Nadie le presta atención a los carteles de ayuda (a Ninguno), esa es una verdad indiscutible, yo opino que una pregunta que solo incluya imágenes, a veces ni siquiera le ponen texto no debe ser aceptada por el motor, incluyo aquella que tenga menos de 50 caracteres.

Comment: Se podría analizar la imagen después de subida haciendo un proceso de reconocimiento OCR, si se detecta que se puede sacar texto de la misma y este texto es código, solo en este momento mostrar una advertencia clara, grande y visible de que no se debe subir código en forma de imágenes.

Comment: @ElChiniNet Esa es una idea excelente!

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso ese limite es inutil. De hecho, ya existe. Y en las preguntas vas a ver cosas como "Esto lo escribí para que el sistema me permita publicar la pregunta (ignorar): aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...". Vi eso al menos una vez.

Comment: En realidad, no se si existe... Lo estube tratando de obtener creando una pregunta de prueba pero no dio resultado. Incluso cuando traté de publicar una sola imagen. Quizá sea un tema de reputación, pero incluso si es así, yo creo que publicar una sola imagen sin texto no aporta nada sin importar tu reputación.

Comment: Podríamos directamente tomar una decisión drástica, toda pregunta dónde el código necesario se muestra como imagen, se cierra por que "Necesita detalles o  aclaraciones", no sé si se puede pero estaría bueno agregar debajo el texto "Esta pregunta debería incluir más detalles para clarificar el problema. Se ha puesto el código como imagen y no como texto".

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que se podría agregar como nuevo **motivo de cierre**: **"Tu pregunta no es inclusiva"**. Y decir que no es inclusiva sé que suena intenso, pero es la mera verdad.

Te explico. Allá hace unos años cuando este sitio estaba en beta y yo estaba en mis primeros trabajos un Ruslan López muy novato y entusiasta trataba de colaborar para que creciera este sueño colectivo que conocemos con el apodo de SOes (Soez para los más procaces). Y da la casualidad que estaba en el gobierno de mi país en una institución de apoyo social, es decir, si manejaban dinero, pero no es que estuviera en el banco mundial o algo así... era una dependencia tercermundista para la gente más pobre mi país, y a alguien se le ocurrió la idea de poner un firewall muy hijuep** que bloqueaba las imágenes de stack overflow.

Me llegó a pasar que preguntaba con una imágen, me hacían preguntas de la imágen y una vez publicada yo ya no la podía ver... mala suerte si era una captura de pantalla.

Eso mismo me impedía responder a los usuarios que preguntaban usando alguna imágen, la mayoría en ese momento se tomaban a bien que les pidiera que no usaran imágenes, pero mira que con unos pocos nos dábamos abasto para responder las preguntas... hoy esto ha crecido bastante y por ello sugiero el motivo de cierre.

**Sé que es drástico.** Y que el que te cierren tu pregunta casi siempre es una sentencia de muerte, porque deberás esperar los años para que la reabran, pero el tener imágenes sin texto alternativo, con capturas de el problema de alguien que no es considerado con los demás como lo somos los que tratamos de responder no me parece nada recíproco, ni nada amable tampoco.

Tratar de mejorar instrucciones al crear tu pregunta que **nadie quiere leer** no es el problema, **ni vale la pena dañar la experiencia del usuario que pregunta metiendo una sarta de validaciones para preguntar**, yo creo que el enfoque correcto es mediante un nuevo motivo de cierre.

Comment: "inclusiva" creo que sería "incluyente" en dado caso. Sin embargo creo que el título **no es demasiado intuitivo**, yo recomendaría que fuera algo como **"El código no tiene el formato adecuado"**. Pero a favor de agregar ese motivo de cierre

Comment: Hay personas con dificultades visuales, ciertamente el código como imagen y no como texto no es "inclusivo"

Comment: En mi opinión, claramente debería ser un motivo de cierre. En cuanto al término "inclusivo", no lo se, quizá tiene otras connotaciones, pero mal no está. Dicho sea de paso, trabajé para el BM en mi país y el proxy bloqueaba imgur :), el repositorio que usa SO para las imágenes.