# Ejemplos reales en el recorrido

Tags: discusión, recorrido

Hoy estuve mirando revisando el **recorrido** para poder identificar el por que de tanta pregunta de baja calidad, y observo los ejemplos con los que explican son un poco confusos para los usuarios por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como evitar que los unicornios ? - la pregunta de ejemplo solo cuenta con texto

Propongo que los ejemplos que se muestran en la parte derecha de la pantalla donde están las fechas sean mas reales mas intuitivos ya que este tipo de imágenes se pueden prestar para dar por hecho que con el solo texto mi pregunta esta bien.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente:

Parte 1.

¿Ejemplos mas reales ayudarían a los nuevos usuarios para guiarse en la formulación de sus preguntas?

Claro, de modo que lo vean incluso como una *plantilla* tal vez para estructurar la suya viendo en la guía factores como:

- Formato al código
- Explicación previa (lo que se ha hecho hasta el momento)
- Explicación posterior (el resultado que se busca obtener)
- Comportamiento visualizado (el error o resultado actual y el cual es motivo de hacer la pregunta aquí)

Parte 2.

Sin embargo....

También esta el otro factor que me ha tocado ver y que a continuación enlisto:

- Usuarios cuyo perfil indica que llevan meses o quizás años en la plataforma y siguen respondiendo y/o preguntando sin un mínimo de calidad en las publicaciones (lo cual puede indicar alguno de los siguientes factores)

  - No son usuarios regulares de la plataforma (pudiera indicar ser ajenos al material provisto para ayudarse)
  - A pesar de tener la medalla que se otorga por realizar el *tour* no se han detenido a analizar detalladamente lo que este ofrece
  - No revisan el perfil de los usuarios que mas puntaje tienen por responder y/o preguntar y que les pudiera significar de ayuda en notar que elementos tienen carentes en su propia publicación
  - Cuando en la zona de comentarios reciben retroalimentación respecto a su publicación, no la siguen y dejan que su pregunta se llene de votos negativos tal vez...
- Tenemos por otro lado a los usuarios nuevos que llegan con la intención de resolver una duda por que (lo he leído) **les han recomendado la plataforma**, pero al no revisar toda la ayuda provista siguen sin asimilar del todo lo esperado de la comunidad por parte de ellos y ellas por lo cual se topan con:
- preguntas y/o respuestas cerradas
- votos negativos
- que sientan que no se les quiere ayudar **(esto último lo leí en una publicación hace días, pero se causa esta confusión por que nosotros esperamos algo de sus publicaciones que ellos o ellas no aportan pues no han leído y aplicado la ayuda provista y ellos o ellas esperan una ayuda de nosotros que tal vez no llegue por que no atienden a lo esperado de sus preguntas que nosotros deseamos leer en las mismas)**

¿Por qué menciono el aspecto de ver las preguntas de otros usuarios?

Bueno por que lo que hacemos en la plataforma marca muchas veces el camino que los mas nuevos(as) siguen para interactuar y si nos vamos a la página 1 de los miembros por reputación veremos aportaciones excelentes de:

- abulafia: Da explicaciones tremendamente detalladas, no solo provee código sino que además explica el por que y que camino tomar para resolver un problema
- PaperBirdMaster: Una persona que guía de manera didáctica y técnica a muy excelente nivel en la resolución de problemas de código.

Si nos vamos a la página 4 tenemos a compañeros como:

- DavidJP cuyas respuestas en el área de MySQL indican un nivel claro no solo de dicho software sino que trata de orientar en la mejor solución expuesta, como referencia: [Mostrar consultas de forma mas optima MySql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283591/mostrar-consultas-de-forma-mas-optima-mysql/283653#283653)

> **Claro esta que solo coloco algunos ejemplos, pero como ellos muchos mas**

Los anteriores claro esta son solo **algunos** de los muchos usuarios que ayudan en esta comunidad y cuyas publicaciones cumplen con la calidad esperada, las cuales pudieran *(aunque no de modo estricto)* dar una *luz* de como ser partícipe aquí.

> Todo lo anterior lo menciono por que si bien es cierto que una parte del trabajo para las publicaciones de calidad le corresponde a la plataforma al tener guías de calidad, también es cierto que *algunos* usuarios solo ven en la comunidad el espacio para resolver tareas o dudas de modo express pero no se terminan de enrolar en la dinámica esperada.

Entonces aquí uno de los elementos que mas pudieran ayudar son:

- Si es imposible de rescatar la publicación, entonces votar para cerrarla pero dejarle los enlaces oficiales en la zona de comentarios para esperar que los consuma y le sirvan para elevar la calidad de su aporte
- Tal vez si solicitar que los ejemplos de muestra sean mas *aterrizados* a muestras de código con una estructura mas cercana a la que nosotros esperamos leer en una pregunta real
- Importante, para aquellos que si podemos entrar en las colas de revisión, en especial en *Votos de reapertura*; entrar para ver si se pueden reactivar algunas preguntas y así también el *OP* note que como se cierra su pregunta por alguna causa justificada así mismo también se abre si cumple con las reglas.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, tal vez no dar ejemplos de código en si, si no,estructurar un código de ejemplo estándar o algo parecido pues que no sea solo texto ya que puede confundir,créeme también me he topado con gente que tiene 100 de reputación y siguen haciendo muy malas preguntas y dando muy malas respuestas, o tambien se podria poner como obligatorio el recorrido no se esto minimizaria este tipo de preguntas, cuando digo obligatorio que sea algo basico que no tome mucho tiempo.

Comment: aqui una respuesta a el recorrido oligatorio https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4003/recorrido-obligatorio-y-eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-im%c3%a1genes-para-usuarios-nuevos