# como puedo subir código , ya que tengo problema

Tags: soporte, preguntas

**al poner un codigo completo me sale siempre "parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles."**

algun consejo o forma de poder subir bien el codigo

Comment: Pon la descripcion del codigo o la pregunta por debajo del codigo

Comment: Amigo @Benjaminmorabrito como ha dicho el usuario pollo, existe `stackoverflow meta` el cual resuelve dudas de usuarios relacionados a la pagina, creo que esta pregunta seria bien recibida ahi, ya que stackoverflow no es para preguntas acerca de una duda de la pagina si no mas bien dudas de codigo en si.

Comment: Estas escribiendo mil lineas de codigo y la descripcion es no me funciona? estas poniendo todo tu codigo, y solo escribes como mejorarlo? la idea de una pregunta es poner un [mcve] y describir tu problema.. muchas veces, muchisimas partes de tu codigo no son necesarias...

Answer (score 8):

Está muy bien que hayas agregado tu código, pero te faltó explicar con tus palabras de qué se trata. La solución es que te tomes un tiempo y agregues una descripción además de tu código, que describas qué pasa, si está disparando algún error, cuál es el resultado esperado, y qué intentaste para resolverlo.

Esa advertencia que estás recibiendo es *exactamente* para evitar que se publiquen preguntas como la que estabas por hacer. Las preguntas que son sólo código tienen varios problemas. Entre los principales:

- No aclara qué pasa. Se pierde más tiempo leyendo el código para entender cuál es ese maldito problema antes de entender qué se está preguntando. -Yo seguramente cierre la pestaña y pase a otra cosa sin terminar de leer la pregunta.
  Te recomiendo seguir y cumplir con cada uno de los puntos de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- Demuestran que no hay ni siquiera un mínimo esfuerzo por parte de quien pregunta por establecer una comunicación normal. Si el autor de la pregunta ni siquiera se toma unos minutos para explicar qué es lo que le está pasando, ¿no te parece que quien la lea va a tener menos ganas de responder? Además, si solamente pegás el código, parece bastante maleducado, como si pretendieras que alguien acá trabajara para vos.
- Tampoco le sirven al autor de la pregunta, porque suelen no tener la suficiente información para comprender el problema puntual. Lo más probable es que termine con respuestas a diferentes errores dentro del mismo código que no le interesaban o no eran de la forma que quería resolverlo el autor de la pregunta o, peor aún, terminan sin que nadie se interese por responderlas.
- No le sirven a otros con tu mismo problema, porque sería realmente difícil que encuentren tu pregunta cuando no tiene nada de texto.
- Se supone que deberías reducir tu código a un problema puntual, que se pueda reproducir con la menor cantidad de código posible, y explicarlo. Dejame citarte lo que dice al final de [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

  > - Describe el problema. “No me funciona“ no es una declaración útil. Dinos cuál debería ser el comportamiento esperado. Cuéntanos cual es la redacción exacta del error que se produce y en qué linea se está produciendo. Pon un resumen breve del problema en el título de tu pregunta.
  > - Elimina todas las cuestiones no necesarias al problema. Si tu pregunta no es acerca de un error de compilación, asegúrate de que no haya errores de ese tipo. Usa un programa como JSLint para validar lenguajes interpretados. Todo el HTML y XML debe ser verificado.
  > - ¡Asegúrate de que el ejemplo reporta el problema en la actualidad! Si solucionaste el problema inadvertidamente mientras preparas el aporte pero no lo pruebas de nuevo, sería bueno saberlo antes de pedir ayuda.

Actualmente el límite son 6 caracteres de texto por cada línea de código ([fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4051/193460)).

---

---

Dicho esto, ¿por qué no te das una pasada por [las preguntas más votadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) del sitio? Quizás no todas, pero vas a notar que la mayoría son muy claras a la hora de describir el problema.

Comment: ya lo resolví y pude subir una pregunta , muchas gracias por su tiempo , de vdd muy agradecido